# How to uninstall .NET Core 1.0.0 from mac?

Tags: .net

I installed .NET Core 1.0.0 on my mac from [Microsoft .NET Core Installation Site](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos). I want to uninstall it. I could not find any steps online. Please help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is an uninstall script mentioned in the RC1/RC2 [**upgrade roadmap**](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/1.0/RC1-RC2_Upgrade.md) document (note that I haven't tried this myself, but this is where I'd start):

> #### Windows
>
> On Windows, simply use the Add/Remove programs in the Control Panel to
>   remove all the previous versions of the .NET Core bits. Please note
>   that we have changed the name that appears in Add/Remove programs from
>   ".NET Core CLI" to ".NET Core SDK"; please use the latter to search
>   for installed versions to remove.
>
> #### Ubuntu
>
> In order to make life easier, we have created a script for cleaning up
>   all versions of .NET Core from a machine. You can get the script from
>   https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh.
>   Please note that this will remove any and all previous versions, which
>   means the machine will be cleaned completely of any .NET Core bits.
>   The script needs elevated privileges, so it needs to be run under
>   sudo.
>
> #### OS X
>
> In order to make life easier, we have created a script for cleaning up
>   all versions of .NET Core from a machine. You can get the script from
>   https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh.
>   Please note that this will remove any and all previous versions, which
>   means the machine will be cleaned completely of any .NET Core bits.
>   The script needs elevated privileges, so it needs to be run under
>   sudo.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Some additional info for mac users: Save `dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh` to your machine, then run `sudo sh dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh`. Make sure that you have the full path pointed to `dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.hs`. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/235129/86512